# Output of a short int and a unsigned short?

Tags: c, unsigned, twos-complement

So I'm trying to interpret the following output:

```
short int v = -12345;
unsigned short uv = (unsigned short) v;

printf("v = %d, uv = %u\n", v, uv);

Output:
v = -12345
uv = 53191
```

So the question is: why is this exact output generated when this program is run on a two's complement machine?

What operations lead to this result when casting the value to `unsigned short`?

Comment: Looks right to me.  What result did you expect?

Comment: @SteveSummit Actually it seems incorrect to me... According to http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2 it should be `53190`. If I am reading it correctly...

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are not reading it correctly ;-)

Comment: @P.P. Please explain where this one is coming from

Comment: @P.P. Oh! Nevermind. I've read it about 10 times until got it right.

Comment: I was just trying to understand why but the answer below helped me. thank you.

Comment: @FilipeConceição I would rather focus on the formal answer referring the standard. It is not representation-specific, the result will be the same for *any* representation (where the sizes of the types are the same)

Answer (score 3):

My answer assumes `16-bit` two's complement arithmetic.

To find the value of `-12345`, take `12345`, complement it, and add `1`.

```
12345 is 0x3039 is 0011000000111001.
```

Complementing means changing all the `1`'s to `0`'s and all the `0`'s to `1`'s:

```
1100111111000110 is 0xcfc6 is 53190.
```

Add one: `53191`.

So internally, `-12345` is represented by `0xcfc7 = 53191`.

But if you interpret it as an unsigned number, it's obviously just `53191`.  (And when you assign a signed value to an unsigned integer of the same size, what typically ends up happening is that you assign the exact bit pattern, without converting anything.  Later, however, you will typically interpret that value differently, such as when you print it with `%u`.)

Another, perhaps easier way to think about this is that `16-bit` arithmetic "wraps around" at 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536.  So you can think of `65536` as being another name for `0` (just like `0:00` and `24:00` are both names for midnight). So `-12345` is `65536 - 12345 = 53191`.

Comment: thank you so much... I was doing just that but somehow I got lost. The last sentence is really a nice way to look at it.  :)  thank you

Comment: The first part of the answer has nothing to do with the question in the context of C language. The behavior does not depend on "2-complementness" of the machine. Conversion and reinterpretation are two completely different concepts. In this case we are dealing with a conversion. No reinterpretaton involved at all. Trying to explain it through a reinterpretation is misleading to say the least.

Comment: @AnT My answer was not intended to address the C language at all: it explained two's complement arithmetic, which is what the OP asked about.  The parenthetical about "interpretation" was deliberately vague, but I've reworded it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion rules, when converting signed integer to an unsigned integer, defined by C standard requires by repeatedly adding the TYPE_MAX + 1 to the value.

From [6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.3p2):

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.

If `USHRT_MAX` is 65535 and then adding `65535` + `1` + `-12345` is `53191`.

Answer (score 2):

The output seen does not depend on 2's complement nor 16 or 32- bit `int`.  The output seen is entirely defined and would be the same on a rare 1's complement or sign-magnitude machine.  The result does depend on 16-bit `unsigned short`

-12345 is within the minimum range of a `short`, so no issues with that assignment.  When a `short` is passed as a ... argument, is goes thought the usual promotion to an `int` with no change in value as all `short` are in the range of `int`.  `"%d"` expects an `int`, so the output is `"-12345"`

```
short int v = -12345;
printf("%d\n", v);  // output "-12345\n"
```

---

Assigning a negative number to a unsigned type is well defined.  With a 16-bit `unsigned short`, the value of `uv` is -12345 plus the minimum multiples of `USHRT_MAX+1` (65536 in this case) to a final value of 53191.

Passing an `unsigned short` as an ... argument, the value is converted to `int` or `unsigned`, whichever type contains the entire range of `unsigned short`.  IAC, the *values* does not change.  `"%u"` matches an `unsigned`.   It also matches an `int` whose values are expressible as either an `int` or `unsigned`.

```
short int v = -12345;
unsigned short uv = (unsigned short) v;
printf("%u\n", v); // output "53191\n"
```

---

> What operations lead to this result when casting the value to unsigned short?

The casting did not affect the final outcome.  The same result would have occurred without the cast.  The cast may be useful to quiet warnings.

Comment: that I didn't now...thank you all for your help. It really helped me understand this.